# Merge by date multiple log files that also include un-dated lines (e.g. stack traces)

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, merge

How can I merge log files, i.e. files that are sorted by time but that also have multi-lines, where only the first line has the time, and the remaining ones have not.

**log1**

```
01:02:03.6497,2224,0022 foo
foo1
2foo
foo3
01:04:03.6497,2224,0022 bar
1bar
bar2
3bar
```

**log2**

```
01:03:03.6497,2224,0022 FOO
FOO1
2FOO
FOO3
```

**Expected result**

```
01:02:03.6497,2224,0022 foo
foo1
2foo
foo3
01:03:03.6497,2224,0022 FOO
FOO1
2FOO
FOO3
01:04:03.6497,2224,0022 bar
1bar
bar2
3bar
```

If it weren't for the non-timestamp lines starting with a digit, a simple [`sort -nm log1 log2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26247085/709537) would do.

Is there an easy way on a unix/linux cmd line to get the job done?

**Edit** As these log files are often in the gigabytes, merging should be done without re-sorting the (already sorted) log files, and without loading the files completely into memory.

Comment: Is this an actual UNIX or do you mean Linux? Do you have the GNU tools?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tricky. While it is possible using `date` and bash arrays, this really is the kind of thing that would benefit from a real programming language. In Perl for example:

```
$ perl -ne '$d=$1 if /(.+?),/; $k{$d}.=$_; END{print $k{$_} for sort keys(%k);}' log*
01:02:03.6497,2224,0022 foo
foo1
2foo
foo3
01:03:03.6497,2224,0022 FOO
FOO1
2FOO
FOO3
01:04:03.6497,2224,0022 bar
1bar
bar2
3bar
```

Here's the same thing uncondensed into a commented script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## Read each input line, saving it 
## as $_. This while loop is equivalent
## to perl -ne 
while (<>) {
    ## If this line has a comma
    if (/(.+?),/) {
        ## Save everything up to the 1st 
        ## comma as $date
        $date=$1;
    }
    ## Add the current line to the %k hash.
    ## The hash's keys are the dates and the 
    ## contents are the lines.
    $k{$date}.=$_;
}

## Get the sorted list of hash keys
@dates=sort(keys(%k));
## Now that we have them sorted, 
## print each set of lines.
foreach $date (@dates) {
    print "$k{$date}";
}
```

Note that this assumes that all date lines and *only* the date lines contain a comma. If that's not the case, you can use this instead:

```
perl -ne '$d=$1 if /^(\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+),/; $k{$d}.=$_; END{print $k{$_} for sort keys(%k);}' log*
```

---

The approach above needs to keep the entire contents of the files in memory. If that is a problem, here's one that doesn't:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/\0/; s/^/\n/ if /^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/' log* | 
    sort -n | perl -lne 's/\0/\n/g; printf'
01:02:03.6497,2224,0022 foo
foo1
2foo
foo3    
01:03:03.6497,2224,0022 FOO
FOO1
2FOO
FOO3    
01:04:03.6497,2224,0022 bar
1bar
bar2
3bar
```

This one simply puts all lines between successive timestamps on to a single line by replacing newlines with `\0` (if this can be in your log files, use any sequence of characters you know will never be there). This passed to `sort` and then `tr` to get the lines back.

---

As very correctly pointed out by the OP, all of the above solutions need to be resorted and don't take into account that the files can be merged. Here's one that does but which unlike the others will only work on two files:

```
$ sort -m <(perl -pe 's/\n/\0/; s/^/\n/ if /^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/' log1) \
            <(perl -pe 's/\n/\0/; s/^/\n/ if /^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/' log2) | 
    perl -lne 's/[\0\r]/\n/g; printf'
```

And if you save the perl command as an alias, you can get:

```
$ alias a="perl -pe 's/\n/\0/; s/^/\n/ if /^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/'"
$ sort -m <(a log1) <(a log2) | perl -lne 's/[\0\r]/\n/g; printf'
```

Comment: The problem with this is it loads the contents of all files into memory first. As the files already are sorted, this should be easy to avoid and do in a streaming fashion (with a general purpose language such as Perl, with which I'm not familiar with, so it's not easy for me :)

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy I don't see how. The files are  not sorted, that's the whole problem. They're only sorted within each file, however, you can find `line1` and `line3` in `fileA` while `line2` is in `fileB`.  I don't see how you can sort that without either using temp files or storing in memory. If you would rather have tmp files, let me know and I'll give you an example.

Comment: It's not that complicated: You read in the first line of every file, then you output the oldest line plus any undated multi-lines of that file that follow and forget all those lines. Then you move on to the file that now has the oldest line and do the same. You repeat the process alternating between files until exhausted. If that doesn't make sense to you, you can verify that something like this *must* be possible by e.g. monitoring `ps -eo comm,vsz|grep perl` while perl is running vs. `sort -nm log*`. I tried it with 3 files totaling 650MB. Max mem for your solution: `863 MB`,for sort: `8 MB`

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy yes, as I said, it is possible using temporary files (that's what `sort` does). I see what you're describing but implementing a full sort algorithm is way beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: 1) I wasn't asking for the implementation of a sort algorithm 2) In order to merge already sorted files, full sorting is not necessary, as explained in my last comment. 3) Even if sorting was indeed necessary, it still would not mean someone had to reinvent the wheel here. There might e.g. be some little-known flag in some unix command.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy I still don't understand how you could merge without either storing the data in memory or in a temporary file (which is what `sort` does). Perhaps there is a way but, if so, I don't know it. You will need to be able to insert one file into the middle of an another so some kind of data structure will be needed. Anyway, have a look at the updated answer, I've posted a new approach that only ever keeps a single line in memory.

Comment: Thanks terdon - Newline replacement was the idea I needed! I've posted an answer using your idea, avoiding the unnecessary re-sort of your answer.

Comment: I will accept your answer. I only edited your answer and added a caret to your regex and made it more specific to prevent mismatches. Thanks for your help - good lesson for me.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy your edit was rejected before I had the chance to review it so I did it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I too have seen unwarranted rejections of helpful edits from other people to my answers before. My version btw was even more strict: `^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}` . But that's not crucial to this question any more.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (thanks @terdon for the newline replace idea):

1. Concat all multilines to single lines by replacing those newlines by e.g. NUL in each input file
2. Do a `sort -m` on the replaced files
3. Replace NUL back to newlines

**Example**

As the multiline concatenation is used more than once, let's `alias` it away:

```
alias a="awk '{ if (match(\$0, /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\./, _))\
    { if (NR == 1) printf \"%s\", \$0; else printf \"\\n%s\", \$0 }\
    else printf \"\\0%s\", \$0 } END { print \"\" }'"
```

Here's the merge command, using above alias:

```
sort -m <(a log1) <(a log2) | tr '\0' '\n'
```

---

**As shell script**

In order to use it like this

```
merge-logs log1 log2
```

I put it into a shell script:

```
x=""
for f in "$@";
do
 x="$x <(awk '{ if (match(\$0, /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\./, _)) { if (NR == 1) printf \"%s\", \$0; else printf \"\\n%s\", \$0 } else printf \"\\0%s\", \$0 } END { print \"\" }' $f)"
done

eval "sort -m $x | tr '\0' '\n'"
```

Not sure if I can offer a variable number of log files without resorting to evil `eval`.

Comment: Nice, +1. Though I have to say that `awk` seems needlessly complex. Why not use the much shorter perl version in your alias?

Comment: I tried to use your perl, but the problem is it always adds a newline at the beginning. The fix of that same issue btw is what makes the `awk` solution so complex. Your perl will look similar I guess. The reason I switched to awk is just that I'm not a perlist.

Comment: Ah, to get rid of the blank line, just pass it through `grep .`: `perl -ne 's/\n/\0/; s/^/\n/ if /\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/ ; print' log* | tr -s '\0' '\n' | grep .` Or even `awk 'NR>1'`.

Comment: You are the man, terdon. You've got all the good ideas. Except, `grep .` also swallows blank lines that existed originally. Your `awk` is safe though, as would be `tail -n+2`.

Comment: Your perl is significantly faster than my awk. However, the `tr -s` that has to come with your current perl solution however removes empty lines that existed in the original. In general that's good enough, but the result is not a perfect merge.

Comment: Ah, true. OK, I posted a new version that i) uses `sort -m` ii) doesn't eat blank lines and iii) doesn't add extra ones. And then it will turn out that something like `logrotate` can do all this automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

When using Java is an option for you, try [log-merger](https://github.com/siom79/log-merger):

```
java -jar log-merger-0.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar -f 1 -tf "HH:MM:ss.SSS" -d "," -i log1,log2
01:02:03.6497,2224,0022 foo
foo1
2foo
foo3
01:03:03.6497,2224,0022 FOO
FOO1
2FOO
FOO3
01:04:03.6497,2224,0022 bar
1bar
bar2
3bar
```

Comment: If only Java didn't take that long to start up, I would immediately switch to writing shell scripts in [some decent JVM language](http://clojure.org/)!

Answer (score 0):

Try [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 log1 log2
```

However, *Super Speedy Syslog Searcher* expects to find a datetime stamp. If you can change the logging format to that then `s4` can sort it.